# No Database option in Silverlight project

Tags: wcf, ria

I am creating a silverlight 4 project (with web site). When I try to add a data source to the project, I dont see database option in the list of options. There are only "service", "object" and "sharepoint" options. But there is no "database" option there. So I am not able to bind to database at design time.

I want to know what is the reason and why it is like that, is something not installed or any configuration mistake?

Can somebody pls tell me.

I am using Visual studio 2010 Professional.

Thanks

Comment: The whole point is: Silverlight runs in the client's browser - and you don't typically get to have a database in your client's browser. Silverlight's architecture is to use WCF (RIA) Services to provide data to display.

Comment: hi marc, the thing is, I have created a wcf ria project also, but there also I dont see database option in the list of options. There are only "service", "object" and "sharepoint" options. But there is no "database" option there. So I am not able to bind to database at design time.

I want to know what is the reason and why it is like that, is something not installed or any configuration mistake?

Can somebody pls tell me.

I am using Visual studio 2010 Professional.